# How to plot a CI only in the predicted line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used a GNM (Generalised Non-Linear Model) to make a prediction and stored all the data in a data frame. I also stored a `pred_up` and `pred_down` variables, which are simply the upper and lower part of the confidence interval, which I would like to plot as a shaded area. By the code bellow I get the following chart

```
ggplot(plot_males, aes(x = year, y = real_data)) +
        geom_line(aes(color = "Obs"), na.rm=TRUE) +
        geom_line(aes(x = year, y = pred, color = "Prediction"), na.rm=TRUE) +
        geom_line(aes(x = year, y = pred_up, color = "CI"), na.rm=TRUE) +
        geom_line(aes(x = year, y = pred_down, color = "CI"), na.rm=TRUE)
```

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is something like the chart bellow, with the confidence interval area shaded. I know that the ggplot2 has a way of plotting confidence intervals directly but it does not has a GNM method so that is why I am storing my upper and lower CI intervals in the dataset.

Is there a way of shading the interval?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `geom_ribbon`.

Comment: You can pass arbitrary model functions and -parameters to ‘ggplot2’s `stat_summary` function, so you *can* plot a GNM CI with it. … but of course if you’ve already calculated the CI then there’s no need to recompute it.

Comment: See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlraa/vignettes/Bootstrapping.html#confidence-bands-for-generalized-nonlinear-models) for an example of how to use geom_ribbon() with your pre-calculated confidence bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
geom_ribbon(aes(x = year, ymin = pred_down, ymax = pred_up), 
              fill = "red", alpha = 0.15, na.rm = TRUE)
```